How to simulate keyboard pressed through python
I need to simulate OK button or ESC button pressed through python for my addon. I found this post, but it only works for windows, I'm working on Linux and MacOS, is there any unified way to achieve such purpose?
My use case is to kill a window by bpy.context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog() when something changes. My current status is that when I call the operator's invoke function (The operator's invoke function returns a popup window.), the old window persists.
I tried @Gorgious method, it does close the popup, but it won't call operator anymore. So no new popup window shows up anymore. I need the new popup window.


Hello, if you want to close a popup you can just run bpy.context.window.screen = bpy.context.window.screen. Hacky, but it works.

@Gorgious It does close the popup window, but it won't call operators after this anymore, I need to call operator's invoke function which returns invoke_props_dialog(). The bpy.context.window.workspace and bpy.context.window.screen behave the same, close the popup, but won't open the popup again. I also tried the bpy.context.window.scene, nothing happened.

Unfortunately Blender is not designed with overlayed windows in mind, isn't it possible to draw all of this in a panel in the interface somewhere ?

@Gorgious Yes, that's one option, but the data normally is large, I think it would be better to display them in a separate window. I may reconsider to put them in a panel in the interface since the interface is scalable whatever you want, my ultimate purple is to adjust the window size based on the data contents.
